# Удаление класса, ожидание, добавление другого класса

Tags: jquery

Я хочу перед удалением элемента, проиграть анимацию от `animate.css`

Элемент просто удаляется, а анимация и `delay` игнорируются - что делаю не так ?

```
$('.element').first().removeClass('bounceInUp').addClass('fadeOut').delay(2000).remove();
```

**UPD: и так**

```
$('.newElement').first().removeClass('bounceInUp');
$('.newElement').first().addClass('fadeOut');
$('.newElement').first().delay(2000);
$('.newElement').first().remove();
```

Comment: может попробовать сделать поочередно операции, а не все в одну строку? так вроде все нормально

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц без разницы

Answer (score 1):

Не вижу проблемы - сейчас поддержка, что jQuery, что CSS, позволяет творить чудеса :-)

```js
var oElement = $('.newElement').first();
oElement.removeClass('bounceInUp');
oElement.toggleClass('fadeOut');
oElement.one('animationend', function(e) {
  oElement.remove();
  console.log('newElement удалён!');
});
```

```css
.oldElement {
  border: 1px dashed #090;
  width: 150px; height: 150px;
}
.newElement {
  border: 1px dotted #f00;
  width: 50px; height: 50px;
}
.fadeOut {
  animation: 2s ease-in 0s 1 normal forwards fadeOut;
}
@keyframes fadeOut {
  0% { margin-left: 0px; }
  60% { margin-left: 100px; opacity: 1; }
  100% { margin-left: 100px; opacity: 0; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="oldElement">
  <div class="newElement">newElement</div>
</div>
```

[Источник](https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/using-jquery-to-detect-when-css3-animations-and-transitions-end)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#1s").click(function(){
   $('.newElement').first().removeClass('bounceInUp');
$('.newElement').addClass('fadeOut');

setTimeout (function(){
            $('.newElement').removeClass('fadeOut');
         }.bind(this), 3000);
});
```

```css
.newElement.bounceInUp{
color:red;
}

.newElement.fadeOut{
color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="newElement bounceInUp">
asd
 <button id="1s"/>
</div>
```